# Change amplitude in step function

Tags: scipy, signals

Can the amplitude of the step function in `Scipy` Signal be changed?

The amplitude in the step function has a default value of `1`.  Can the amplitude be increased or decreased?

```
sys = ct.tf([10], [20, 1])

# Generate step response
(y, T) = ct.step(sys)
plt.plot(T, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `ct`?  Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be copied and run without being edited?

Comment: FYI: If you are computing the step response of a linear system, then the response of the system to a step of size C is just C times the unit step response.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid response but i guess since its a linear function you can multipy the output of the stepfunction with the factor you wanna increas the stepfunction by. So lets say you wann multiply the sep function by 100 you just take that as m and multpy y by it

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
K_p=1
T_p=3
m=100
num=[K_p]
den=[T_p,1]
sys=signal.TransferFunction(num,den)
t,y=signal.step(sys,X0=0,N=1000)
plt.figure(1)
y=y*m
plt.plot(t,y,'r-')
plt.show()
```